# A Ri-diddley-iley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is not real,
>   My infix just for he,
>   My suffix moves to and fro,
>   Overall, I symbolise three

**What am I?**
**In your answer, please explain each line.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My prefix is not real,

> sham - a fake imitation

My infix just for he,

> Mr - mister

My suffix moves to and fro,

> rock - moving back and forth

Overall, I symbolise three

> shamrock - with its 3 leaves.  Happy St Patrick's Day!